# QPainter methods return "Painter not active" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qpainter

I'm new to Qt5/PyQt5 and want to create a single rectangle object, append it to a list and draw it in a window, but it fails with Painter not active errors.

What's the reason for this?

Errors:

> QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
>
> QPainter::drawRects: Painter not active

Code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRectF
from PyQt5 import QtCore

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsRectItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush

rectangles = []

class Rectangle(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Rectangle, self).__init__()
        self.brush = QBrush(QtCore.Qt.blue)


    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.setBrush(self.brush)

        self.setRect(10, 10, 300, 300)
        painter.drawRect(10, 10, 200, 200)


    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0,0,800,800)


class GraphicsWindow(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)

        rectangle = Rectangle()
        rectangles.append(rectangle)
        scene.addItem(rectangle)

        scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 800, 800)
        self.setScene(scene)
        self.setCacheMode(QGraphicsView.CacheBackground)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    graphics_window = GraphicsWindow()
    graphics_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I've already tried this, but it produces another error.

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "/home/ata/source/Tests/rect.py", line 16, in paint

        painter = QPainter(self)

    TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:

      QPainter(): too many arguments

      QPainter(QPaintDevice): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Rectangle'

Comment: remove `painter = QPainter()`

Answer (score -2):

in your paint method you already have a painter object, I am not sure hy you are doing ***painter = QPainter()*** instead of using that painter(if that is valid refernce to an object), anyways, you are creating a new painter object, so before you paint anything, the following code is actually c++ code but since qt is a language independent framework, the way to go is the same...

```
painter.begin(this);
painter.doSomePicasso(); //paint what you need
painter.end();
```

---

in python should be something like

```
qp.begin(self)
self.drawText(event, qp)
qp.end()
```